# normal closure of a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=M_{p^{r+1}}= \langle a,b \mid a^{p^r}=b^p=1,a^b=a^{1+p^{r-1}} \rangle $ be a finite group of order $p^{r+1}$. I want to find $\langle b \rangle ^ G$, the normal closure of $\langle b \rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$If $r = 1$, then $G$ is abelian, thus the normal closure of $\Span{b}$ is $\Span{b}$.

If $r \ge 2$, then
$$
(a^{p})^{b} 
= 
(a^{b})^{p} 
= 
(a^{1 + p^{r-1}})^{p}
=
a^{p + p^{r}}
=
a^{p},
$$
so that $a^{p}$ is central in $G$.

Since $a^{p^{r-1}} \in \Span{a^{p}}$, $a^{p^{r-1}}$ is also central, and thus $\Span{a^{p^{r-1}}}$ is normal in $G$.

Moreover the relations show that $G/\Span{a^{p^{r-1}}}$ is abelian, so that by the correspondence theorem every subgroup containing $a^{p^{r-1}}$ is normal in $G$.

Now the normal closure of $\Span{b}$ contains
$$
b^{-1} (b)^{a^{-1}}
=
b^{-1} a b a^{-1}
=
a^{b} a^{-1} 
=
a^{p^{r-1}}.
$$
By the above, $\Span{b}^{G} = \Span{a^{p^{r-1}}, b}$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$@Hana, please note the correction of a misprint, if $r = 1$ then the normal closure  of $\Span{b}$ is $\Span{b}$, not $G$ as I had previously  written. And then, if $r \ge 2$, note that $\Span{b}^{G} = \Span{a^{p^{r-1}}, b}$ has order $p^{2}$.

Comment: Yes that right, thank you so much for your attention

Comment: I posted a new question in my profile but it put on hold! can i ask you help me to solve my question"the number of the subgroups of a finite group ". Thank you so much

Comment: @Hana you post questions that appear as advanced exercises, without any show of effort on your part, as required by the guidelines. That is why your questions have been put on hold.